# RHEL yum broken

Tags: redhat, yum, rpm

I have RHEL which is deployed from Amazon AMI, and yum is somehow broken. I must use that AMI because of corporate software installed on it. There is no way to rollback to previous state.
This is the output of all yum commands except yum delete:

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-208 ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, security
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 309, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 178, in main
    result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 345, in doCommands
    self._getTs(needTsRemove)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 101, in _getTs
    self._getTsInfo(remove_only)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 112, in _getTsInfo
    pkgSack = self.pkgSack
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 661, in <lambda>
    pkgSack = property(fget=lambda self: self._getSacks(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 501, in _getSacks
    self.repos.populateSack(which=repos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 232, in populateSack
    self.doSetup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 79, in doSetup
    self.ayum.plugins.run('postreposetup')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 179, in run
    func(conduitcls(self, self.base, conf, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/rhui-lb.py", line 89, in postreposetup_hook
    path = urlparse.urlparse(repo.mirrorlist)[2]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urlparse.py", line 50, in urlparse
    tuple = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urlparse.py", line 89, in urlsplit
    i = url.find(':')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Seems to break while parsing the repo list, check your repos, also try  the yum plugins and see if that helps.

Comment: Find the person who created the AMI and have them fix it.

Comment: I've solved it. It is known bug in RHEL 5.5 when instance is in Amazon VPC. Source: 
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/44250

Answer (score 0):

Update your yum package to the lastest one.
This is related to a yum bug which was fixed.

```
Red Hat Bugzilla – Bug 1070879
```